# Set TextBox Based on Value From DropdownList (populated by database) on initial Load

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have problem to set currency texboxt from dropdown at initial load, it only change after the dropdown change, that dropdown populated by database using codebehind c# and for dropdown change I use ajax

well here's the code
dropdown

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPaymentCurrency" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" onblur="showCRate2()" onChange="showCRate2()" onkeyup="showCRate2()"></asp:DropDownList>
```

and function ddlPaymentCurrency onchange

```
function showCRate2(obj) {
            this.curr();
            var selectedCurrency = $('#<%=ddlPaymentCurrency.ClientID%>').val();
            console.log(selectedCurrency);
            if (selectedCurrency != null && selectedCurrency != "") {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "TopUp.aspx/getCurr",
                    data: '{id:"' + selectedCurrency + '"}',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {
                        var o = response.d;
                        $('#<%=hfCurrencyRate.ClientID%>').val(o.RateBuy);
                        $('#<%=hfCR.ClientID%>').val(o.RateBuy);
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert('error')
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

and the webmethod

```
[WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public static MukyaServiceReference.CurrRate getCurr(int id)
        {
            var CR = client.GetCurrRates(id);
            return CR;
        }
```

Anybody can help?

Comment: Is there a default value in the drop down?

Comment: No default value for dropdown

Comment: Then what value do you want to show without calling on change?

Comment: @psylogic okay example when page load dropdownlist(ddl) automatically set position at 1st list, so I want the textbox set the first  value so...

Comment: may i know when you bind the dropdown?

Comment: check out the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you'll have the value of the first item of the dropdown selected and in the text box. Using jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#ddlPaymentCurrency').val( $('#ddlPaymentCurrency option:first-child').val() );

$('#yourTextBoxId').val($('#ddlPaymentCurrency').val());

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the textbox's value according to the dropdown list value on page load or using JQuery at the frontend

Comment: ,Sorry, Have you  try it on Page Load?
I already try to get that value on page load using selectedValue before,  on page load the dropdownlist did'nt  selected value yet. 
. If use JQuery but still confuse how to get it value during that dropdownlist without change